# Ubuntu 18.04 : file creation problem

Tags: permissions, apache2, mysql, php

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my machine two days back.  Its a fresh installation on a new hard disk.

I have an application that was built on PHP 5.5.9 & MySQL 5.5.61.  When I installed PHP on the new os, by default PHP 7.2.10 and MySQL 5.7.24 got installed.  The application allows the users to create folders and upload files.  While the folders are getting created, the files were not getting uploaded.  I am getting the error:  `The path is not writable. Please check your permissions`.

I did the following:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
sudo chmod o+w -R /var/www/
```

as a final step

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/
```

None of this helped.  I removed php7.2 and installed php5.6.  Still facing the same issue.

Comment: `php -v` what is the output?

Comment: @ghost many thanks for your help....since the ubuntu was a fresh installation and I was running out of time - I formatted the disk again and installed ubuntu the all over...with the current installation...I ensured that I install php5.6 after purging out php7.2 that comes as default.....which worked.  Thank you again.